# Blender cursor changing when importing meshes

Tags: interface

Ever since I've updated to 2.9 after every import my cursor turns to a black box with 4 digits inside of it. Now this is not a massive issue, and I initially thought it had to do with the time it takes to compute high poly imports, but apparently it does so even with a simple default cube. I don't remember this happening in older versions (or at the very least not for such long periods of time). Does anyone know how to fix this and what this cursor modification represents?

[image]

Thank you!